# Size of decision tree for f is polynomial in the DNF size of f and CNF size of f

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, machine-learning, boolean-functions, combinatory-logic, boolean-formulas

I've been having hard time with proving the following claim:
Let $f:\{T,F\}^n\rightarrow \{T,F\}$ be a boolean function. Let $size_{DT}(f)$ denote the number of leaves in the smallest (w.r.t the number of leaves) decision tree for $f$. Also, let $size_{CNF}(f),size_{DNF}(f)$ denote the number of clauses, terms in the minimal $CNF,DNF$ formulas for $f$ respectively.

Prove that $size_{DT}(f)\in poly(n,size_{DNF}(f),size_{CNF}(f))$.

Comment: I just learned that this claim is incorrect, check:
http://lovelace.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/ftp/dt.ps

Comment: It would be good to that as an answer and explain why it answers your question a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by the OP (user13772), this is false.  Jukna et al. constructed explicit Boolean functions $f$ that require deterministic decision trees of size $2^{\Omega(\log^2 N)}$, where $N$ is the number of monomials in a minimal DNF for $f$ and $\lnot f$.  Note that every Boolean function on $n$ inputs can be expressed as a deterministic decision tree of size $2^{O(\log n \log^2 N)}$.

- S. Jukna, A. Razborov, P. Savický, I. Wegener, *On P versus NP$\cap$co-NP for decision trees and read-once branching programs*, Computational Complexity **8** (1999), 357–370.  doi:[10.1007/s000370050005](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s000370050005)  ([preprint](http://lovelace.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/ftp/dt.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "number of leaves in a decision tree", as the decision tree is usually a full tree.
If you mean the number of nodes in a BDD (where you can essentially omit unnecessary tests), then I'm pretty sure you can construct a BDD that is at most the size of a DNF formula - simply test each clause "separately" (i.e. on a different branch), this can take at most the length of the DNF representation.

Comment: Actually, I just learned that this claim is false. Check:http://lovelace.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/ftp/dt.ps